# Why was Alex Murdaugh sentenced so quickly after the guilty verdict?

Tags: criminal-law, trial, sentencing

Normally, isn't there a big pre-sentencing investigation and victim impact statements and stuff like that?

Not surprized about the withering rebuke and sentence, but that it occurred so immediately after the verdict.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody who would have given a victim impact statement wished to speak to the court: Erik Ortiz, NBC, "[No victim impact statements](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/live-blog/murdaugh-sentencing-live-updates-rcna73228#rcrd11223)". And the prosecution did not seek the death penalty: N'dea Yancey-Bragg, USA Today, "[Former South Carolina attorney Alex Murdaugh sentenced to life after murder convictions](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2023/03/03/alex-murdaugh-sentencing-murder-conviction-updates/11389486002/)".

Comment: plus: the judge hadn't even have any other option but Life in prison and thus didn't need to elaborate a lot on that either.

Comment: @Trish The lack of discretion is the key issue. If there had been discretion the defendant would have had and would have exercised a right to make a statement prior to sentencing asking for leniency.

Comment: @Trish To elaborate, GA normally requires 30-life or death for murder. The death penalty was not pursued, but an aggravating circumstance, double murder, made it mandatory life. ([S.C. Code § 16-3-20](https://www.scstatehouse.gov/code/t16c003.php) (B) and (C)(a)(9))